# Convert std::chrono::milliseconds to ISO 8601 string

Tags: c++, date, c++-chrono, iso8601

I've a `std::chrono::milliseconds` representing epoch unix time in milliseconds. I need to convert it into a string that follows the ISO 8601 format, like `2020-02-25T00:02:43.000Z`.

Using [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library I was able to parse it, with following `GetMillisecondsFromISO5601String` method:

```
#include "TimeConversion.hpp"
#include <date/date.h>

using std::string;
using std::string_view;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;

string TimeConversion::GetISO8601TimeStringFrom(const milliseconds& ms) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  date::to_stream(ss, "%FT%T%z", ms);
  return ss.str();
}

milliseconds TimeConversion::GetMillisecondsFromISO5601String(string_view s) {
  std::istringstream in{ std::move(string(s)) };
  in.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);
  date::sys_time<milliseconds> tp;
  if (*s.rbegin() == 'z') {
    in >> date::parse("%FT%T%z", tp);
  }
  else if (*s.rbegin() == 'Z') {
    in >> date::parse("%FT%T%Z", tp);
  }
  else {
    in >> date::parse("%FT%T%", tp);
  }
  return tp.time_since_epoch();
}
```

How can I do the inverse? I was trying `to_stream` in the `GetISO8601TimeStringFrom` method as you can see but without any results (it returns me an empty string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're treating a time `duration` (`milliseconds`) as a `time_point` (`time_point<system_clock, milliseconds>`).  All you need to do is convert the `duration` to `time_point` with explicit conversion syntax.  The [date lib](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) has a convenience type alias for this type:  `sys_time<milliseconds>`:

```
string TimeConversion::GetISO8601TimeStringFrom(const milliseconds& ms) {
  date::sys_time<milliseconds> tp{ms};
  // continue using tp ...
```

You may also use the more convenient `format` function in place of `to_stream`:

```
string TimeConversion::GetISO8601TimeStringFrom(const milliseconds& ms) {
  return date::format("%FT%T%z", date::sys_time<milliseconds>{ms});
}
```

Comment: But this will create an ISO8601 date/time string. What if I want to create an ISO8601 duration string?

Comment: You can stream and format durations as well.  When you stream them (e.g. `cout << d`) you get the value and the units with no space in-between.  If you use `format` you can use flags such as `%T`.  If you try to extract a date from a `duration` with `format` you will get a run-time error.  If you are referring to section ISO 8601 section 4.4.3.2 Format with designators, that is not directly supported by `format`, but you could easily use this library to extract average years and and average months from durations and then print those if desired.